# Change form action based on select field option on submit button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which I want to redirect to a particular page on my website according to the option selected in `<select>` tag. For example, if I select 2checkout it should go to gateways/2checkout/2checkout.php and similarly if selected Payza then it should go to gateways/payza/payza.php and so on. This should happen on click of submit button. How can I achieve this?

Example Form:

```
<form method="post" action="gateways/<gateway_folder>/<gateway_file.php>">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 30%">Amount</th>
            <td>
                <span style="display: flex"><span class="currency">$</span>
                <input type="text" id="amount" required class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" style="max-width: 100px" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"></span>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th>Payment Gateway</th>
           <td>
               <select name="gateway" class="form-control col-sm-3">
                   <option value="2checkout">2Checkout</option>
                   <option value="payza">Payza</option>
                   <option value="paypal">Paypal</option>
               </select>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Recharge" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="2">Note: Any currency conversion is done as per updated currency rate using Google Currency Conversion API.</td>
       </tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait till the user submits the form and then read the value from the select, this way you don't need to run the jQuery code over and over:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  let action = $('[name=gateway]').val();
  $(this).attr('action', 'gateways/' + action  + '/' + action + '.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$("[name=gateway]").change(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();
    $("form").attr("action","gateways/"+val+"/"+val+".php");
})
```